# error C2665 when building luabind

Tags: c++, boost, lua, luabind

I'm using *Lua5.1* and *Boost 1.58.0* to try and build *luabind-0.7.1-rc1*. Environment variables are all set properly. I've been searching for an answer for this for about a week now without success.

Whenever I try to build luabind I get 20 of the same error:

```
error C2665: 'boost::operator ==' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types
s:\luabind-0.7.1-rc1\luabind\object.hpp 542 1
```

All the errors seem to be thrown from the last two lines before #undef:

```
// Needed because of some strange ADL issues.

#define LUABIND_OPERATOR_ADL_WKND(op) \
  inline bool operator op( \
      basic_iterator<basic_access> const& x \
    , basic_iterator<basic_access> const& y) \
  { \
      return boost::operator op(x, y); \
  } \
 \
  inline bool operator op( \
      basic_iterator<raw_access> const& x \
    , basic_iterator<raw_access> const& y) \
  { \
      return boost::operator op(x, y); \
  }

  LUABIND_OPERATOR_ADL_WKND(==)
  LUABIND_OPERATOR_ADL_WKND(!=)

#undef LUABIND_OPERATOR_ADL_WKND
```

And here's some of the output itself(it repeats like this):

```
s:\luabind-0.7.1-rc1\luabind\object.hpp(542): error C2665: 'boost::operator ==' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types
          s:\boost_1_58_0\boost\function\function_base.hpp(750): could be 'bool boost::operator ==(boost::detail::function::useless_clear_type *,const boost::function_base &)'
          s:\boost_1_58_0\boost\function\function_base.hpp(738): or       'bool boost::operator ==(const boost::function_base &,boost::detail::function::useless_clear_type *)'
          s:\boost_1_58_0\boost\function\function_base.hpp(809): or       'bool boost::operator ==<luabind::detail::basic_iterator<luabind::detail::basic_access>>(Functor,const boost::function_base &)'
          with
          [
              Functor=luabind::detail::basic_iterator<luabind::detail::basic_access>
          ]
          s:\boost_1_58_0\boost\function\function_base.hpp(800): or       'bool boost::operator ==<luabind::detail::basic_iterator<luabind::detail::basic_access>>(const boost::function_base &,Functor)'
          with
          [
              Functor=luabind::detail::basic_iterator<luabind::detail::basic_access>
          ]
          while trying to match the argument list '(const luabind::detail::basic_iterator<luabind::detail::basic_access>, const luabind::detail::basic_iterator<luabind::detail::basic_access>)'
```

Does anyone have insight or experience with this problem?
What could be causing this error, how can I fix it, and how can I avoid it in the future?

Comment: _"Environment variables are all set properly"_ is not a helpful statement: let us be the judge of what is set properly and what is not as it is you who has not been able to determine what has gone unexpectedly wrong! Show us the environment variables, I guess, if you think they're important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an older boost library. luabind 0.7.1 is from 2008. Try a Boost version from around the same year. I had the exact same problem with luabind 0.8.1 and Boost 1.58.0.

In my case 1.55.0 worked great and it works with vs2013. Apparently older versions of Boost needed to be patched for vs2013.

Answer (score 1):

You can now (sept 2015) switch to [luabind 0.9](https://github.com/luabind/luabind) instead of using version 0.7.